# A recent CPU of 80 TDP or less suitable for Nofan CR-80EH

Tags: processor

The fanless CPU cooling company Nofan has produced the model [CR-80EH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HW2O2L2) which according to the linked webpage can be used for CPUs of up to 80 TDP.

Is there a recent CPU of 80 TDP or less suitable for Nofan CR-80EH? By "recent" I mean produced on year 2022 or 2023.

Comment: Like the latest Ryzen 5 CPUs although I don't remember their power usage. It always has been around 70W though AFAIK

Comment: You do need a new bracket for that cooler though if you want to use it with a modern CPU

Comment: New bracket is an "adapter" right? Aren't these cpu cooling adapters/adjustors be good?

Comment: New bracket is an "adapter" or "adjustor" right? Something to help fixate the cooling.

Comment: The bracket is not an adapter, it's the thing that holds it tight to the CPU. Although the only CPUs that thing supports are around the AM3 era